# Pivot Table changes formatting on new filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

A problem I'm running since developing a report to my client is that cell formatting I implement always get change on new data (By choosing a filter option)

So for example I have:

Title Filter -> A, B, C

Then my PivotTable prints the title.

So I chose title A in Filter so the Pivot Table shows: A

I decide to show the title as bold letter so I bold the title cell, then it becomes: **A**

But when I choose B, the Pivot Table will show: B

Which is not what I expecting since I change the cell formatting to bold the letter so I'm expecting to get **B** instead of B.

Previously I fix the problem by using Conditional Formatting and putting the condition as TRUE but one of the requirements I overlook was Wrap Text which can't be set using conditional formatting so I am back to square one.

Edit: By Filter I mean Slicer in PowerPivot

Comment: What's the meaning of Title Filter? Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, should have put it as slicer instead of filter.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out from multiple trials and error, Pivot Table doesn't want to have different alignment from different cells. It will only accept changes when the whole table is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the entire pivot column (not the entire Excel column - that is too much), i.e. everything from the header to the grand total. Once that area is formatted, it will stick